Controlling which texture is displayed in textured viewport shading
Since it uses up less data, I like to use the viewport shading with texture as the color option most often. An issue I commonly come across is that it will display the normal map of the material instead of the diffuse texture. Is there a way to make it so that Blender always shows the diffuse texture (base color) when textured viewport shading is on?
